# Run monkeyrunner without the phone plugged to the PC

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

i want to run a python stability test-case with monkeyrunner

however i want to run the script without having the mobile plugged to the PC (because what is measuring is battery life)

Normally I use "monkeyrunner mytest.py "

So the idea would be executing the py script with a monkeyrunner inside the phone.Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use two approaches:

1. To use monkey command locally on Android device and write your own script (the syntax for this command differs from monkeyrunner syntax)
2. You can use the approach proposed by @Gabriel Porumb . But you should use the command in the following way:

At first you should run command:

```
adb tcpip <port>
```

Then on your device you should check what ip address is assigned to your device (you can check this in the Settings).

After that you have to execute command:

```
adb connect <your_ip>:<port>
```

And now you can run your monkeyrunner script.

Comment: Could you please provide informations about the first approach? Thank you.

Comment: You can read about it here: http://basic-operating-system-faq.blogspot.it/p/monkey-script.html Be careful, maybe you will need to check Android sources to launch the script (AFAIR, I had some problems with my script and I needed to check the sources of Android to write it properly).

Comment: @Yury **method 1:** run monkey command locally is not work without root or system signature. To run monkey command locally, app has to get permission `"android.permission.SET_ACTIVITY_WATCHER",` which protectionLevel is `"signature"`.

Answer (score 0):

The monkeyrunner script runs on the PC only. However, if you don't want to connect the phone to the PC via cable, you could try connecting via wifi. Use:

```
adb connect 192.168.x.x
```

Or something like that to connect to the phone.